# HTML Radio Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

http://jsfiddle.net/8sbt5oua/8/

I would like to get my code only concentrated on a few everytime.
Instead of all of them, who could help me?

[image: gif]

```
    <input id="01" type="radio">
    <input id="02" type="radio">
    <input id="03" type="radio">
    <input id="04" type="radio">
    <input id="05" type="radio">
    <input id="06" type="radio">
```

```
var btn = document.getElementById("02");
setInterval(function() {
  var list=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    btn = list[i];
    btn.checked == false ? btn.setAttribute("checked", "checked") : btn.removeAttribute("checked");
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: why is your jsfiddle not clickable?

Comment: What do you wish to accomplish with this code ? What should this line do : `var btn = document.getElementById("02");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8sbt5oua/10/

First have two arrays that you want to flicker on and off.

```
var arr1 = [0,1,2];
var arr2 = [3,4,5];
```

You also want a global variable that toggles between the two.

```
var use_first = true;
```

Then you want to use the toggling variable to determine which one toggles on and which ones toggles off.

```
let remove;
let checked;

if (use_first)
{
    checked = arr1;
  remove = arr2;
}
else
{
    checked = arr2;
  remove = arr1;
}
```

And I think the foreach explains themselves since they're basically your code.

Edit:

```
remove.forEach(function(item, index)
{
    btn = list[item];
  btn.removeAttribute("checked");
});
checked.forEach(function(item, index)
{
    btn=list[item];
  btn.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
});
```

Comment: How can I "not" randomize this but say the first time, only button 02, 03, 06, second time 01, 04, 05. I would like to make a whole page of these buttons but want to precisely say which sound blink and which shouldn't because I also want a few to not blink at all. (they will become an image at the end, so I need to precisely say which should blink.)

Comment: Updated. Let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: Is there a possibility that the code doesn't work in Safari?

Comment: Can't say, I don't own a mac.

Comment: Then another question, If I want to do for example in var arr1 = [1,2,3] and in var arr2 = [2,4,6] the 2 doesn't show up, how could I fix that?